# JSF - p:dataTable - p:commandButton doesn't work even inside p:column

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces

I have a commandButton inside a DataTable. However the "action" isn't called when I click on it (same effect with an actionListener); I added logs at the beginning of the server action, and it never shows. 
Please note that the button works fine when outside from the datalist.

Here is my code:

```
<h:form id="compSearchForm">
    <p:dataTable var="competency" value="#{competencySearchBean.matchingCompetencies.toArray()}">
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputLabel value="Title" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{competency.title}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <p:commandButton value="Go" id="actionButton" action="#{myBean.doAction}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Would you have any idea as to what the issue might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added your button column code to an existing  of mine along with a dummy method in by backing bean.  The method is called correctly when I press the button it works correctly.  Here is the code I added to my dataTable:

```
<p:column>
    <p:commandButton value="Go" id="actionButton" action="#{tableBean.buttonAction()}" />
</p:column>
```

Here is the buttonAction method in my backing bean:

```
public void buttonAction()
    {
        int a = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            a = i;
    }
```

I put a breakpoint on this method, so I know it is getting called when I click the button.
I went a step further and used your datatable code (with my data source) and the method is still being called when I press the button. I don't know what development environment you are using, but if it has a debug mode put a breakpoint on your doAction method, and a few other strategic locations in your bean, then run your project in debug mode to see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for your help Sean. I am on Tomcat 7, JSF 2.0, PrimeFaces 2.2RC1. The obvious difference I can see between our calls is that you call "buttonAction()" with parenthesis. I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: Seems to work :) Thanks a lot for your help (even though it still feels weird that adding parenthesis makes it work).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change to:

```
<h:form id="compSearchForm">
<p:dataTable var="competency" value="#{competencySearchBean.matchingCompetencies.toArray()}">
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputLabel value="Title" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{competency.title}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
<p:commandButton value="Go" id="actionButton" action="#{myBean.doAction}" />
</h:form>
```

I don't think you can have the button inside the dataTable. Try this.

Comment: This indeed works, but it is not exactly what I would like to do. I would like to have a button / link / icon on each row, and when the user clicks on it, an action is performed that depends on the row data.

Comment: If you are using seam, you can use an `s:button` which will work as you want. This is because it will perform a GET and not POST. You can also try to encapsulate the `<h:form>` inside the datatable so that each row gets its own form, if you want to post each row

Comment: I tried to add a new f:form inside the datatable, but if I do this nothing is displayed anymore. There is no javascript error though, so I don't really know why.

Answer (score 0):

see this example - http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionByColumn.jsf

I think you must prefix the id with the form ID

see how it updates ":form:display" instead of only "display"

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after trying different ways, I resolved it by initializing my `List` (the list that I use in the `p:datatable`) in the `init` method of the `Bean`.

With this form, the list goes to the page with some values.

Even when I put `List<Paciente> myList = new ArrayList<Paciente>();` it didn't work.
I have to put some values in the list. That was the only way that resolved the problem.

Comment: I honestly doubt this answer is in any way related to this problem.